# Can you warn people that their Towny rent is almost due?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

In [Towny](http://xshade.ca/projects/towny/), is it possible to warn players a certain time before rent is due if they won't be able to afford rent?

I'm open to installing further plugins to enable this, but it's rather painful to my players to have to replace torches and reclaim areas if they don't remember to pay rent and they lose their plots/towns.

Comment: Get a landlord to put up signs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned later that this is a feature request, but isn't an actual feature yet. Star the request and help get the developer's attention. =)

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/towny/issues/detail?id=257&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Label%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary